# excel linear transformation

Tags: statistics

Does anyone know how to do this linear transformation in excel?

1800    723 650 600 372 326 326 204 153 150 150 87  84  57  53.5    51  51  47  45  45  42  40  30.6    29.2    28.5    20  20  16  14  11.7    9   9   9   7   6   6   6   3   3   3   2

Basically if I set the first number to 100 and the last number was 1, what would the numbers in between be? For example, 723 may be close to 42 or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a linear transformation.

$y=a+b\cdot x$

$x$ is the original value

$y$ is the transformed value

$1800$ has to become $100$. Thus the first equation then is $100=a+b\cdot 1800$.

$2$ has to become $1$. The second equation is $1=a+b\cdot 2$.

Now you can use this to equations two calculate the values of $a$ and $b$.

You will see that the original value of $723$ will be transformed to the value of $40.70$.

*practical advice using Excel:*

You input the orignal values into the cell range $A1$ to $A100$. Then input the formula **=a+b*A1** into the cell $B1$. a and b are the values of the parameters you have calculated. Use the [fill handle](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/7.4) to copy the formula into the cells range $B2$ to $B100$.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in excel. Thanks Callculus.

Comment: @FPat I´ve made an edit and input some information how to use excel.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate it!

Comment: @FPat You´re welcome.